# MySQL ROLL UP query

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

I have this mysql query that has a problem with the last line. I want only the last column (total) and the rest of the rows i want them NULL.

QUERY:

```
SELECT q.id_socio, q.nome, q.nif, q.num_mecanografico, SUM(IFNULL(qt.quota_nova, quota)) AS 'quota'
FROM 
    (SELECT id_socio, quota_nova FROM QUOTAS_TEMPORARIAS WHERE ANO = 2019 AND MES = 10) 
    AS qt 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT id_socio, nome, nif, num_mecanografico, quota FROM SOCIO s, TIPO_PAGAMENTO tp, AGRUPAMENTO a, ORGANIZACAO o WHERE s.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO = tp.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO AND s.id_agrupamento = a.id_agrupamento AND a.id_organizacao = o.id_organizacao AND o.id_organizacao = 1 AND s.id_tipo_pagamento = 1) 
    AS q
ON q.id_socio = qt.id_socio 
GROUP BY q.id_socio WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING q.nome IS NOT NULL AND q.nif IS NOT NULL AND q.num_mecanografico IS NOT NULL OR q.id_socio IS NULL
```

Result:

[image]

Expected results:

[image]

Comment: What is "the problem"? Can you share the input data, such that others can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Remove the `Having` clause and add the other columns to the `Group By q.id_socio, q.nome, q.nif, q.num_mecanografico`. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

> A MySQL extension permits a column that does not appear in the `GROUP BY` list to be named in the select list. (For information about nonaggregated columns and `GROUP BY`, see Section 12.20.3, ["MySQL Handling of GROUP BY"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).) In this case, the server is free to choose any value from this nonaggregated column in summary rows, and this includes the extra rows added by `WITH ROLLUP`.
>
> This behavior is permitted when the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL` mode is not enabled. If that mode is enabled, the server rejects the query as illegal because the column is not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. With `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled, you can still execute the query by using the `ANY_VALUE()` function for nondeterministic-value columns.
>
> ***source:*** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

**You have two possibilities:**

1.) Add the columns `q.nome`, `q.nif` and `q.num_mecanografico` to the `GROUP BY`.

2.) You can use a CASE WHEN to set NULL on the last row (where `q.id_socio` is `NULL`):

```
SELECT q.id_socio,
  CASE WHEN q.id_socio IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE q.nome END AS nome, 
  CASE WHEN q.id_socio IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE q.nif END AS nif,
  CASE WHEN q.id_socio IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE q.num_mecanografico END AS num_mecanografico,
  SUM(IFNULL(qt.quota_nova, quota)) AS 'quota'
FROM 
    (SELECT id_socio, quota_nova FROM QUOTAS_TEMPORARIAS WHERE ANO = 2019 AND MES = 10) 
    AS qt 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT id_socio, nome, nif, num_mecanografico, quota FROM SOCIO s, TIPO_PAGAMENTO tp, AGRUPAMENTO a, ORGANIZACAO o WHERE s.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO = tp.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO AND s.id_agrupamento = a.id_agrupamento AND a.id_organizacao = o.id_organizacao AND o.id_organizacao = 1 AND s.id_tipo_pagamento = 1) 
    AS q
ON q.id_socio = qt.id_socio 
GROUP BY q.id_socio WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING q.nome IS NOT NULL AND q.nif IS NOT NULL AND q.num_mecanografico IS NOT NULL OR q.id_socio IS NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=333ef2a770c866c77106706f2cb82914)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to do something like this.

```
WITH main_query AS (
    SELECT
        id_socio,
        nome,
        nif,
        num_mecanografico,
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT
                quota_nova
            FROM QUOTAS_TEMPORARIAS temp_quota
            WHERE id_socio = temp_quota.id_socio
                AND ANO = 2019
                AND MES = 10),
            quota) quota
    FROM SOCIO socio,
        TIPO_PAGAMENTO tipo_pag,
        AGRUPAMENTO agrup,
        ORGANIZACAO org
    WHERE socio.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO = tipo_pag.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO
        AND socio.id_agrupamento = agrup.id_agrupamento
        AND agrup.id_organizacao = o.id_organizacao
        AND org.id_organizacao = 1
        AND socio.id_tipo_pagamento = 1
)
    SELECT * FROM main_query
UNION
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(quota) FROM main_query

GROUP BY id_socio WITH ROLLUP
HAVING nome IS NOT NULL
    AND nif IS NOT NULL
    AND num_mecanografico IS NOT NULL
    OR id_socio IS NULL
```

You will need to make a Union to include the total line to your results without having the other values.
In fact, I do not recommend doing this, for an application query result 'cause this will need special treatment to recover the total results, I'd suggest to you to use two separated queries.
But it's up to you now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to be sure without seeing the tables and the data referenced, but if those images you posted are correct then this should work: Store dataset into two temporary table then union the tables to get the desired data:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1
SELECT q.id_socio, q.nome, q.nif, q.num_mecanografico, SUM(IFNULL(qt.quota_nova, 
quota)) AS 'quota' 
FROM 
(SELECT id_socio, quota_nova FROM QUOTAS_TEMPORARIAS WHERE ANO = 2019 AND MES = 10) 
AS qt 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT id_socio, nome, nif, num_mecanografico, quota 
  FROM SOCIO s, TIPO_PAGAMENTO tp, AGRUPAMENTO a, ORGANIZACAO o 
  WHERE s.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO = tp.ID_TIPO_PAGAMENTO AND s.id_agrupamento = 
  a.id_agrupamento AND a.id_organizacao = o.id_organizacao AND o.id_organizacao = 1 
  AND 
  s.id_tipo_pagamento = 1
 ) AS q ON q.id_socio = qt.id_socio 
GROUP BY q.id_socio 
WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING q.nome IS NOT NULL AND q.nif IS NOT NULL AND q.num_mecanografico IS NOT NULL 
OR q.id_socio IS NULL;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2
SELECT null,null,null,null,quota FROM t1 WHERE id_socio IS NOT NULL;

SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2;
```